# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' google-api-php-client-2.0.1-PHP5_4/vendor/react/promise/src/functions.php on line 15

Tags: php

I am trying to add data on google calendar by PHP.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' google-api-php-client-2.0.1-PHP5_4/vendor/react/promise/src/functions.php on line 15

Answer (score 1):

Line 15 of [`promise/src/functions.php`](https://github.com/reactphp/promise/blob/master/src/functions.php) in React is an array initialisation using the short `[...]` syntax.

```
$canceller = [$promiseOrValue, 'cancel'];
```

This syntax is only valid in [PHP 5.4 or higher](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

I therefore summise you are running PHP 5.3 or earlier. You should upgrade. 5.3 is **7 years old** and security support ended in 2014. In addition a lot of the new features will make your coding experience more pleasant and PHP 7.0 is *considerably* faster.